# javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException

Tags: mysql, jsf, jboss, transactions, seam3

Right now I am experiencing an unpleasant issue. I have 6 projects running on my JBoss AS 7. They are deployed in standalone mode. After working for some time(5-25 hours) I start to recieve identical error in all my projects : **javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException** .

Here is the stack:

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[site.technorational.kz]] (http--192.168.1.2-80-3) Exception sending request initialized lifecycle event to listener instance of class org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionServletListener: javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor136.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_21]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [rt.jar:1.6.0_21]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [rt.jar:1.6.0_21]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355) [rt.jar:1.6.0_21]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308) [rt.jar:1.6.0_21]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$16.work(SecureReflections.java:343) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInstantiation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:173) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.newInstance(SecureReflections.java:340) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:33) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:73) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:162) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:241) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:229) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:207) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.notifyObservers(BeanManagerImpl.java:569) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:564) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:68) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionServletListener.requestInitialized(TransactionServletListener.java:117) [seam-transaction-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_21]
Caused by: javax.transaction.NotSupportedException: BaseTransaction.checkTransactionState - ARJUNA016051: thread is already associated with a transaction!
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.begin(BaseTransaction.java:63)
        at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.begin(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:65)
        at org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction.begin(ServerVMClientUserTransaction.java:142)
        at org.jboss.seam.transaction.UTTransaction.begin(UTTransaction.java:51) [seam-transaction-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.seam.transaction.DefaultSeamTransaction.begin(DefaultSeamTransaction.java:88) [seam-transaction-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionServletListener.requestInitialized(TransactionServletListener.java:110) [seam-transaction-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BaseTransaction.checkTransactionState - ARJUNA016051: thread is already associated with a transaction!
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.checkTransactionState(BaseTransaction.java:257)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.begin(BaseTransaction.java:59)
        ... 13 more
```

After I was searching for answers in the logs I found that sometimes this comes before the previous exception comes out:

```
22:19:21,872 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS018559: Deployed "project1-web.war"
22:19:21,873 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS018559: Deployed "project2-web.war"
22:19:21,873 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS018559: Deployed "project3-web.war"
22:19:21,875 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS018559: Deployed "project4-web.war"
22:19:21,875 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS018559: Deployed "project5-web.war"
22:19:21,876 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS018559: Deployed "project6-web.war"
22:19:21,888 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://192.168.2.1:9990/management
22:19:21,889 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://192.168.2.1:9990
22:19:21,889 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT "Steropes" started in 31119ms - Started 4319 of 4426 services (98 services are passive or on-demand)
22:24:59,256 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX 0:ffffc0a80107:2c60f317:50914f6c:4d in state  RUN
22:24:59,259 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffffc0a80107:2c60f317:50914f6c:4d invoked while multiple threads active within it.
22:24:59,259 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffffc0a80107:2c60f317:50914f6c:4d aborting with 1 threads active!
22:24:59,260 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffffc0a80107:2c60f317:50914f6c:4d
```

I have given a lot of thinking to this issue. One of my suggestions is that MySQL causes that, because there are a lot of methods that are retrieving information from database using **JPA CriteriaBuilder**. When I check status of MySQL, I can see that there are about 100 slow queries.

In my projects I am using SEAM, Hibernate, JPA, PrimeFaces.

I managed to find a some similar issues but not answers still.

Thanks in advance,
Ilya Sidorovich

Comment: Not sure how Seam plays a role here as I've never used it, but to be sure, you're thus nowhere using EJBs?

Comment: We are using EJB in our projects

Comment: There is a exception in the stack trace. Looks like transaction is in invalid state that resulted in this error. Caused by: javax.transaction.NotSupportedException: BaseTransaction.checkTransactionState - ARJUNA016051: thread is already associated with a transaction!

Comment: This issue was tested on JBoss 7.1.1 and JBoss 7.2.0 Alpha. Problem appears on both versions.

Comment: Ye, we got that the problem goes from invalid state of transaction. But I have no idea what causes it.

Comment: Check the thread on https://community.jboss.org/thread/179047 which points to exactly same stack trace on JBoss AS7.1

Comment: Oh? You *are* using EJBs even though you're using Seam? Are you injecting Seam beans in EJBs or the other way round? That might have messed up the transaction management. Try to not inject them in each other. I can't guarantee if this solves the problem as I've never really used Seam. It's purely theoretical.

Comment: Some thread are trying to begin or resume a transaction (explicit in your code or in a implicit way)[rg.jboss.seam.transaction.UTTransaction.begin(UTTransaction.java:51)]. If  resume is invoked when the calling thread is already associated with another transaction, the Transaction Manager throws the  IllegalStateException exception. If begin is invoked when the  when the calling thread is already associated with a transaction and the transaction manager implementation does not support nested transactions, the Transaction Manager throws the  IllegalStateException.

Comment: I have changed default-timeout of transactions to 0 and the problem is gone. But I don't think that it is a good solution. Still can not understand where does it come from.

Answer (score 4):

Here the same problem is experienced: https://community.jboss.org/thread/179047?_sscc=t

Disabling the listener and manually annotating the classes/methods would be one way of fixing it.  If a transaction is marked for rollback, then the listener will roll it back.

It is also possible, that a thread tries to begin transaction that was already rolled back. Thus, in TransactionServletListener.requestInitialized() the transaction status is 4 (rolled back).

Please, refer to the discussion [link](http://community.jboss.org/thread/179047?_sscc=t) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I had this stacktrace when my transaction was expired by the JBoss (AS 7). You can increase your transactions lifetime changing this configuration on your standalone.xml:

Inside the node:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.2">
```

Change this attribute:

```
<coordinator-environment default-timeout="600">
```

The timeout is in seconds.

Note: this errors can be cause by other reasons (Sergey answer is one of them). Usually it happens when your transaction has been finalized or marked for rollback and your process still need it.